# How to disable /application.wadl in OpenAPI spec with Jersey

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, swagger, openapi

## Setup

I use a [Spring Boot app from the Initializr](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.6.3&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=openapi-jersey-demo&name=openapi-jersey-demo&description=Demo%20Project%20for%20OpenAPI&packageName=com.example.openapi-jersey-demo&dependencies=jersey) with Jersey dependency included and add `io.swagger.core.v3:swagger-jaxrs2:2.1.13` as an additional dependency. Then I create the following ResourceConfig (registering other resource classes omitted for brevity):

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        this.registerClasses(
                OpenApiResource.class
        );
    }
}
```

When I start the application and have a look at the generated API spec at http://localhost:8080/openapi.json, I find two paths:

- `GET /application.wadl/{path}` and
- `GET /application.wadl`

In Swagger UI, it looks like this:

[image]

When I send a request to the WADL endpoint, I get a 404 response in this setup. I already tried to disable the WADL feature with this line, but the spec still contains the two paths:

```
this.property(ServerProperties.WADL_FEATURE_DISABLE, true);
```

## Question

How do I disable or hide these two paths in the OpenAPI spec properly?

Comment: Seems like Swagger processing of the Application class happens before Jersey gets to the removal of the Wadl resource. I don't really use Swagger, but maybe [this config (resourcePackages) might work](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Getting-started#your-own-configuration)

Answer (score 1):

The spring doc doesn't support jersey/JAX-RS out of box.
You will need to control the openapi.json generation logic in Jersey resource configuration.

```
OpenApiResource openApiResource = new OpenApiResource();
// change package name
openApiResource.setResourcePackages(Set.of("com.service.resource"));
// you can do a lot of configuration here
// https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Integration-and-Configuration#configuration-properties
register(openApiResource);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try `packages-to-scan` property

```
springdoc:
   packages-to-scan:
    - com.myapp.appName.controller
```